# html5 canvas text animation news ticker

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I have this piece of code foundit here:
https://github.com/shinstudio/html5_myown_party/blob/master/news_ticker/index.html

I need to change ticker scroll from right to left.

canvas js code:

```
<div id="border">
   <canvas id="bannershow" width="500" height="150" />
</div>

var globalx = 0;
var vector = 1;
var interval = 120;
var canvas = document.getElementById('bannershow');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var fontsize = 80;
var canvasHeight = 150;
var canvasWidth = 500;

function banner(label) {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);    
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect (0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)'
    ctx.font = fontsize + 'px Helvetica';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';

    if (globalx > canvasWidth) {
        globalx = ctx.measureText(label).width * -1;
    }
    ctx.fillText(label, globalx, (canvasHeight-fontsize)/2);

    globalx += vector;
}
setInterval(banner, 1000/interval, 'Helvetica is the new font');
```

Comment: I changed my solution a little. Now it loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

globalx is the vraibale which is increasing and taking it from 0 to the width of canvas, just do the inverse of it, and most likely it'll work for you

```
                    function banner(label) {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);    
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
                    ctx.fillRect (0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

                    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)'
                    ctx.font = fontsize + 'px Helvetica';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
                    globalx = canvaswidth;
                    if (globalx > 0 ) {
                         globalx = ctx.measureText(label).width * 1;
                    }
                    ctx.fillText(label, globalx, (canvasHeight-fontsize)/2);

                    globalx -= vector;
                }
```

PS - I haven't tested it, but seems like doing the inverse on globalx by starting with the width of your canvas should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change banner() function to:

```
       function banner(label) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);    
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
            ctx.fillRect (0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)'
            ctx.font = fontsize + 'px Helvetica';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
            if (globalx < ctx.measureText(label).width * -1) {
                 globalx =  canvasWidth;
            }
            ctx.fillText(label, globalx, (canvasHeight-fontsize)/2);

            globalx -= vector;
        }
```

Negative vector will reverse the move and modified condition for globalx will preserve continous looping.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/t74ww/1/

```
var globalx = 500;
var vector = -1;
var interval = 120;
var canvas = document.getElementById('bannershow');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var fontsize = 80;
var canvasHeight = 150;
var canvasWidth = 500;

function banner(label) {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);    
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect (0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)'
    ctx.font = fontsize + 'px Helvetica';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    if (globalx < 0 - ctx.measureText(label).width) {
        globalx = canvasWidth;
    }  
    ctx.fillText(label, globalx, (canvasHeight-fontsize)/2);

    globalx += vector;
}
setInterval(banner, 1000/interval, 'Helvetica is the new font');
```

Just change vector = -1 and globalx = 500. vector is responsible for direction of horizontal scrolling and globalx is startpoint (on x axis) where text is rendered.
It's better to change those variables than to change the function. In fact the animation is controlled by this settings/variables.

Cheers

Comment: try mine solution bellow - it loops

Answer (score 0):

```
                        var globalx = 0;
                        var vector = 2;
                        var interval = 120;
                        var canvas = document.getElementById('bannershow');
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        var fontsize = 120;
                        var canvasHeight = 150;
                        var canvasWidth = 500;

                        function banner(label) {

                            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);    
                            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
                            ctx.fillRect (0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

                            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)'
                            ctx.font = fontsize + 'px Helvetica';
                            ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
                            if (globalx > canvasWidth) {
                                 globalx = ctx.measureText(label).width * -1;
                            }
                            ctx.fillText(label, globalx, (canvasHeight-fontsize)/2);
                            if(globalx==-500)
                            {
                                globalx=50;
                            }
                            globalx -= vector;
                        }
                        setInterval(banner, 1000/interval, 'Helvetica');
```

After checking little bit i found this one this is **looping and working** as well you can change **globalx** value if you want to change interval of that one

```
if(globalx==-500)
{
  globalx=50;
}
```

change this to change interval except that all working well i think this will help you regards...:)

**[update]**

> globax=interval change this **interval**

Comment: this one works...but it hickup on looping...how can I make it go without distortion at the end of the loop

Comment: I describe that you have to change interval globax=interval so you can do that one chge update in my answer